# Function scipy.interpolate.interpn() much too slow

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, interpolation

I am using `scipy.interpolate.interpn()` to interpolate a value at a single point on a 2D grid.
The catch is that for this single point and for the 2D grid, I have to perform many evaluations of the `interpn` function:

```
interpolatedValue = []
for i in range(300000):
  interpolatedValue.append(scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, valueList[i], point)[0])
```

The code works as expected, but is far too slow. For each of these calls, the parameters `point` and `points` are the same. Consequently the interpolation weights determined for each call must be identical. Since the weights are the same, it is inefficient to compute them over and over again.

Can it really be that there is no faster way to do this with scipy?

Comment: Could you please include some example data you are working with? You probably are just mixing the `values` and `xi` arguments of the `interpn` function. In typical use case the two first parameters would be fixed. The third argument can be a numpy array which would save you from looping (and make the evaluation probably faster).

Comment: No, the call is correct as coded. The parameters ```points``` and ```point``` to not change within the loop.

Comment: Could you explaing with example data what you are trying to do?

Comment: On the same grid and at the same point, I am interpolating 300k different functions each sampled on that grid

Comment: I guess you don't have the functions anymore as otherwise you would be calling them directly on `point`? I bet creating interpolators for each of them will really take some time.  I've had some luck in making stuff faster with numba and Cython previously.  Maybe those offer help for you.

Comment: Indeed the functions generating the data to be interpolated are not available

Comment: If the grid is the same at each time, compute the coefficients for, say a biliner interpolation a single time. Imagine that point is at `x[nx] + a (x[nx+1]-x[nx])` (similar in y with `b`). Then the value only depends on the value of the data at `x[nx],y[ny]`, `x[nx+1],y[ny]` (etc for the four corner) with fixed weights depending on a and b. That would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

interpolatedValue = [ scipy.interpolate.interpn( points, value, point)[0] for value in valueList ]